# ¿Cambiar el valor de la propiedad grid-column/row de css con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid-layout

¿Qué tal?

Estoy tratando de cambiar los valores de las propiedades de css

```
grid-column
grid-row
```

con un `mouseover` desde JavaScript pero no se como llegar a ellas, lo que siempre hago es

```
element.style.propiedad
```

pero no se con que palabra acceder a ella.

Hago esta interacción desde JavaScript porque necesito hacer otros cambios junto con que la animación.

Quedo bastante agradecido!

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar tu HTML y CSS por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando una propiedad contiene un guión, al acceder a ella con JavaScript se utiliza *camel case*: se quita el guión y la siguiente letra se hace mayúscula. Así, en CSS es `z-index` pero en JS es `zIndex`, igual ocurre con `border-color` (`borderColor`), `grid-column` (gridColumn) o `grid-row` (`gridRow`).

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo en el que el elemento salta de la fila 3 columna 2, a la fila 1 columna 4 con JavaScript al pasar el ratón por encima:

```js
document.querySelector(".elemento").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  this.style.gridColumn = "4 / 8";
  this.style.gridRow = "1 / 3";
});
```

```css
.migrid {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  background: #bef;
}

.elemento {
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
  background: #369;
  color: #bef;
}
```

```html
<div class="migrid">
  <div class="elemento">AA</div>
</div>
```

Otra manera de acceder a la propieda sería usando la notación de array con corchetes, en cuyo caso no tienes que cambiar el nombre de la propieda (tan solo especificarla como cadena):

```
this.style["grid-column"] = "4 / 8";
this.style["grid-row"] = "1 / 3";
```

Comment: Gracias hermano! Toda una clase completa con esa respuesta!